# visual studio 2010 installer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, installation, database-connection

Need some help I have a problem regarding my program using vb10 it was connected to MYSQL Server 2005 i created my final project as an installer when i install it in other computer there was an error. This is the error "A network or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection (provider: Named Pipes Provider error 40- could not pen a connection to SQL Server")?

i think i have an error in my connection to database 
this is the code that i used:

```
Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"Initial Catalog=enrollment")
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlserver?

Answer (score 0):

For simplification lets call your local PC computer **A** and the computer where you want to install computer **B**. Not sure if you use mySQL or SQL Server but my answer is acceptable for both.

**What is happening?**

Your connection string is telling your program to connect to your his local MySQL in deployed computer **B** (The part where says Data Source=localhost). As the computer **B** does not have a mySQL fails to make the connection (Error message Named Pipes Provider error 40- could not open a connection to SQL Server).

**You have two solutions**:

1. Change your connection string and put the IP of your local PC **A**. The problem is that **B** probably will have no access to **A**. Probably **A** is at your home and **B** at uni. Also you need to configure SQL/MySQL to accept remote connections.
2. Install a local SQL/MySQL in the computer **B**. Then install your DB there (easiest way is restoring a backup so you have tables, data and if you use, store procs, triggers, functions...)

Go for the second one :-)